# How do I set the status bar in iOS to show a message?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I'm looking to set a message just below the status bar, and possibly changing the color of the message (see photo - am looking to set a message where "Sleep Cycle" is at).

However, I've looked at iOS' Human Design Guidelines, but am unable to ascertain what this control is called.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/

Just a point in the right direction will be of great help.

Comment: is it similar to [this](https://github.com/bryx-inc/BRYXBanner)?

Comment: Nope :) This "status bar message" exists outside the app. That seems to be in-app.

Comment: You cannot do that from outside of your app, unless you use some background service like audio recording. And that too system shows it, you have no control over it

Comment: @sandeep The example I've shown above is set my the app Sleep Cycle. The bar exists outside the app. Yes, it tracks your movement in the background.

Comment: @joe Thanks Joe for your detailed answer. I don't think that works outside the app.

Comment: sorry my bad.i didn't looked at the link..hope you find the answer..

Comment: I was reading the doc.its looks like it works with in the app not in background.Its kind of a new approach from apple for the complex app . So, the developers use this utility like a shortcut bar if the app not using navigation bar or toolbar etc. it seems like nothing special.I am sure its available for public API.Keep looking,You will find some answers...

Comment: Maybe you can take advantage from opentok's git repository. I answered something recently.

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

Try this code: Code tested in Xcode 8.

/Update your plist with below code

```
 View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

//In your VC:

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    title = "Some Title"

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent  // To change your status bar to display light content (In white colour)
   }

    func sleepCycleNotify() {

    // To set BannerView
    let barView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:(UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height)))
    barView.backgroundColor=UIColor.red // set to any colour you want..
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(barView)

    let notifyLabel = UILabel()
    notifyLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:(UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height))
    notifyLabel.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    notifyLabel.text = "Sleep Cycle"
    notifyLabel.textAlignment = .center
    notifyLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    notifyLabel.alpha = 0.8
    barView.addSubview(notifyLabel)


    // Animation 1:
    // To achive animation
    barView.center.y -= (navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)!


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations:{
        barView.center.y += (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!


        }, completion:{ finished in



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations:{

                barView.center.y -= ((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)

                }, completion: nil)

    })


}
```

Output from above code:

[image]

//Animation 2:

```
    func sleepCycleNotify() {

    // 
    let barView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:(UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height)))
    barView.backgroundColor=UIColor.red // set any colour you want..
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(barView)

    let notifyLabel = UILabel()
    notifyLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:(UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height))
    notifyLabel.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    notifyLabel.text = "Sleep Cycle"
    notifyLabel.textAlignment = .center
    notifyLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    notifyLabel.alpha = 0.8
    barView.addSubview(notifyLabel)



    // To achive animation
    barView.center.y -= (navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)!


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations:{

        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
        UINavigationController().navigationBar.isHidden = true
        barView.center.y += (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!




        }, completion:{ finished in



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations:{
               // notifyLabel.alpha = 0...1
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
                UINavigationController().navigationBar.isHidden = false
                barView.center.y -= ((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)


                }, completion: nil)

    })


}
```

Output from animation 2:

[image]

Improved Answer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    title = "Some Title"

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.purple
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

  }

    func sleepCycleNotify() {

    // To set BannerView
    let barView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:-UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width:view.frame.width, height:(UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height) + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height ))
    barView.backgroundColor=UIColor.red // set to any colour you want..
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(barView)


    let notifyLabel = UILabel()
    notifyLabel.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width:view.frame.width, height:(UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height))
    notifyLabel.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    notifyLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    notifyLabel.text = "Sleep Cycle"
    notifyLabel.textAlignment = .center
    notifyLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    notifyLabel.alpha = 0.8
    barView.addSubview(notifyLabel)


    // Animation 1:
    // To achive animation
    barView.center.y -= (navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)!


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations:{
        barView.center.y += (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!



        }, completion:{ finished in



            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1.5, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations:{

                barView.center.y -= ((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)

                }, completion: nil)

    })   
}
```

Output from Animation 3:

[image]